# finishLocation seems to work, retUrl does not

Tags: apex, visualforce, visual-workflow, custom-controller

Created a Visualforce page for my flow so I can define a finishlocation :

```
<apex:page controller="InventoryRequestController" showHeader="true" sidebar="true">
    <flow:interview name="Inventory_Request_Flow" interview="{!flowinterview}" finishLocation="{!finishURL}">
        <apex:param name="varUserId" value="{!$User.Id}"/>
        <apex:param name="varFirstName" value="{!$User.FirstName}"/>
        <apex:param name="varLastName" value="{!$User.LastName}"/>
    </flow:interview>
</apex:page>
```

finishURL method from Controller:

```
public PageReference getfinishURL() {
    PageReference p;
    if (flowInterview != null)
    p = new PageReference('/' + flowInterview.newInvReqId + '/e?retUrl=' + flowInterview.newInvReqId);
    else
    p = new PageReference('home/home.jsp');
    p.setRedirect(true);
    return p;
}
```

finishLocation successfully sends me to to the edit page of the newly created Record with the retUrl parameter defined (seemingly), but hitting save takes me to SF home page. How can I properly define the retUrl?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at how that parameter is cased in other parts of the system, I see `retURL`. These url parameters are case-sensitive, and code looking for `retURL` will not find a `retUrl` parameter.